# Hive Split function to select last group

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to split a URL structure and am only interested in the last section of the split.
for eg

```
www.example.com/subdirect/mainpage.aspx
www.example.com/mainpage4.aspx
www.example.com/subdirect/subdiret/subdirect2/mainpage2.aspx
```

here I only want the aspx pages and not the stuff before that i.e i want to return only the below text

```
mainpage.aspx
mainpage4.aspx
mainpage2.aspx
```

I tried using split but I am not sure how to return only the last section of the URL structure dynamically. Any ideas?
This is the script I was trying

```
select split(URL,'/')[MAX] from URLlist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`regexp_extract`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

```
select regexp_extract(URL, '.*/([^/]+)$', 1) from URLlist
```

This will match and capture everything that follows the last `/` character